# why erlang:get_stacktrace/0 get different outputs in shell?

Tags: erlang

consider the code below:

```
 -module(except).
 -compile(export_all).

 divone(X)->    erlang:error({badnews,erlang:get_stacktrace()}),1/X-1.
 tryreturn(X)->

      try divone(X) of
     Val->{result,2/Val}
    catch
    exit:Reason->{exit,Reason};
    throw:Throw->{throw,Throw};
    error:Error->{error,Error}
 end.
```

test the code in shell:

```
 Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)

 1> c(except).
 {ok,except}
 2> except:tryreturn(10). **%why cant't get stack trace info here?**
 {error,{badnews,[]}}          
 3> except:tryreturn(10). **%why can get here?**
 {error,{badnews,[{except,divone,1,
                     [{file,"except.erl"},{line,4}]},
             {except,tryreturn,1,[{file,"except.erl"},{line,7}]},
             {erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,576}]},
             {shell,exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,668}]},
             {shell,eval_exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,623}]},
             {shell,eval_loop,3,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,608}]}]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there hasn't been any exceptions, the stacktrace returned by `erlang:backtrace()` is empty.

Something more helpful than `erlang:backtrace()` for you would be something that includes the instruction pointer and the process's callstack, irrespective of if you've caught an exception.

This should be the ticket:

```
io:format("~s~n", [element(2, process_info(self(), backtrace))]).
```

(Naturally, self can be freely exchanged with another `Pid`)

Comment: but why the second call get the stacktrace info?

Comment: Doesn't require a second call, you can replace erlang:backtrace() with that io:format statement. 

The reason you can see it on the second run is because you've already thrown an exception, which populates the datastructure referenced by erlang:backtrace()

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#get_stacktrace-0):

> Gets the call stack back-trace (**stacktrace**) **of the last exception** in the calling process as a list of `{Module,Function,Arity,Location}` tuples. Field Arity in the first tuple can be the argument list of that function call instead of an arity integer, depending on the exception.

Note the *last exception* in above text. During your first call, there was not any exception yet, so there is not any stacktrace to return. Then you make `error` class[1] exception using `erlang:error/1` so next call returns stacktrace of the previous call!

There is idiom how to get stacktrace of the current code:

```
try throw(foo) catch foo -> erlang:get_stacktrace() end.
```

or using older (*obsolete*) way:

```
catch throw(foo), erlang:get_stacktrace().
```

[1]: There are three classes of exception: `throw`, `error`, `exit`.